# How to apply equality criteria in doctrine findBy condition?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, doctrine-query

Is it possible to apply criteria `>=` condition in Doctrine `findBy`. I have a query like this:

```
select * from source where id >= 10
```

I am looking to apply in following way which will return with reference to Object source.

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository(Source::class)->findBy(['id' ])
```

I can use `createQueryBuilder` but it returns me array result. I need result in same format as above:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->andWhere('s.id >= :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', 10);
```

Expected Result:

```
0 => App\Entity\Source {#845
    -id: 10
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the repository's `matching` method.

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->gte('id', 10));

$repository->matching($criteria);
```

Be aware that doctrine can not always hydrate your database data on Entities, when using custom queries. The result is that it only returns array data.